# How to write a Snowflake Stored Procedure to get a SQL query output in a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can anyone please help me to write a Snowflake Stored procedure to get a SQL query output in a table.
I want to write a snowflake stored Proc which will insert the data into a existing table from a SELECT SQL query output.

Comment: The following page shows an example of how to insert to a table. It's the second one in that section of examples. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#examples. If you try that and are having problems, post the code here for debugging assistance.

Comment: Hi @GregPavlik - Thanks for providing the link, but my requirement is; I need to execute a SELECT SQL query and that output should be inserted into a existing table in Stored Proc.

Comment: If you don't need to process them, just insert them you can run INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT COLA, COLB FROM TABLE2. If you need to process something first, writing what you need in SQL and a description of the processing in the SP will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just execute the statement:

```
INSERT INTO <target_table> SELECT * FROM <source_table>;
```

as a single query inside your SP's JS code.